# Reducing Y-axis in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

[image: Chart.js]
I have a chart which is outputting information correctly but it's too tall. I've looked at the docs and can't find a way to make the Y-axis "smaller". By this, I mean changing the way it is calculate - so in this screenshot it is incrementing by 10s. Is it possible to increment it by, say, 20s? So I have three Y-axis points? This would reduce the height.

For reference, the way Google Analytics outputs data is a good way of doing it. Their charts are nice and slim, making space for other content around them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **`stepSize`** property of y-axis­ ticks. By setting this property to  a value *(interval)* of **`20`** will reduce the y-axis­*'s* ticks count.

```
scales: {
   yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
         stepSize: 20
      }
   }]
}
```

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'LINE',
         data: [10, 30, 20, 50, 60],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)',
         fill: false
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               stepSize: 20 //<-- set this
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```